# Extract DateTime from JSON string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datetime

I have a string:

```
var myJson ="[\r\n  \"2018-08-14\",\r\n  \"2018-08-30\",\r\n  \"2018-11-30\"\r\n]"
```

Which I'm trying to extract the dates from, I thought that I could use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(myJson)
```

but this throws an Unexpected character error.

I could of course simply use find and replace, but I'd like to understand the cause of this error.

Comment: It's because you have an array of `DateTime` try `<DateTime[]>`

Comment: @JPHellemons not quite right. It's an array of `string`

Comment: Just tried @JPHellemons solution in LinqPad and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deserialize it to collection of DateTime, e.g.:

```
var val = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DateTime>>(myJson);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like I commented before, the answer is an array as you can see in the json. It contains multiple datetimes and has square brackets indicating that it's an array.

```
var val = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime[]>(myJson);
```

or `List<T>` like @Alex says.